# ¿Cómo poner enlaces relativos y absolutos?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo montado en un servidor local (bitnami) una aplicación web.
Desde el phpMyadmin gestiono la base de datos. En la modificacion de esta aplicacion, he creado una carpeta: "utilidades" y dentro de ella, estan los ficheros .php por ejemplo:

```
     utilidades/calculoMAC.php
     utilidades/calculoDIV.php
```

El directorio donde esta la aplicación: `C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.29-0\apache2\htdocs\aplicacionWeb`

Y la manera de acceder a esta aplicacion desde el navegador: http://localhost/aplicacionWeb

Hasta ahi todo correcto, pero en la base de datos necesito que se acceda a la por ejemplo a `utilidades/CalculoMac.php`, esto sera parte de una etiqueta html href.

He intentado colocar `../`, `//` y no consigo acceder al fichero mencionado.

Para que funcione correctamente la ruta cuando se accede desde en navegador:
`localhost/aplicacionWeb/utilidades/utilidadesMAC.php`

[image: enlaces de la Bases de datos]

Comment: Hola Javr. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Recuerda leer el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Un saludo

Comment: Desde que ruta estás intentando acceder a http://localhost/aplicacionWeb/utilidades/utilidadesMAC.php ?

Comment: No entiendo a que te estas refiriendo, pero el directorio donde esta instalado el servidor en local es C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.29-0\apache2\htdocs\aplicacionWeb

Comment: Te recomiendo que utilices un virtualhost en lugar de acceder al sitio a través de "http://localhost/aplicacionWeb", de esa forma siempre las rutas partirán del root de la web "/" y solo será necesario moverse hacia delante... "/utilidades/...php"